# how to execute a shell script from any directory

Tags: shell-script

I wrote a simple script with the extension `.sh` in my home directory that I can just run right in my home directory, but I want to run the script from every directory that I am in.  What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interactively, you can always run your scripts by typing `~/yourscript.sh` on the command line, but that's very limiting, especially if you want to write more scripts that call the scripts you've already written.

A more integrated and flexible approach involves putting all your scripts into one directory and adding that directory to your `PATH` environment variable.

After you do that, you'll be able to type `yourscript.sh`, and no matter which directory you're in, the shell will find your script and execute it.

This is how it's usually done:

1. Make a `bin` directory under your home directory and `mv` your scripts into it.
2. Change all the scripts to executable (`chmod +x`).
3. Ensure that your `PATH` environment variable contains your `$HOME/bin` directory. On some systems, the default `~/.profile` will add your `$HOME/bin` directory to the `PATH` automatically, so check your `~/.profile` before modifying.

Let me illustrate with some script:

```
mkdir ~/bin
mv ~/*.sh ~/bin
chmod +x ~/bin/*
if ! grep 'PATH=.*HOME/bin' ~/.profile
then
    echo 'export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
fi
. ~/.profile
echo "$PATH"      # you should see your bin directory
cd /tmp           # change to another random directory
type myscript.sh  # see if the shell finds your scripts
```

If you see your `bin` directory in your `PATH`, then it's a good idea to logout and log back in and change to another directory and execute `type yourscript.sh` again to make sure everything is setup correctly.

Comment: You're welcome. Does this work for you? If you accept this answer you can click the check mark on the left side. Thank you.