# Find and delete all same files (by name) between 2 directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, rm

I want to find all files in dir1 having corresponding same file names in dir2, and delete them from dir1.

For example:

```
dir1: first.txt second.txt
dir2: third.txt first.txt
```

So I want to remove from `dir1` `first.txt` file.

How to achieve this using Bash terminal? (not script with `for` loops etc. or 3'rd party program like "fdupes")

Comment: What's wrong with using `for`? Being able to easily use it in a one-line command is one of the best features of Unix shells.

Comment: Sometimes the things you want to do will require loops or sequences of commands.  You had good luck on the previous question.  The nature of Unix is that you can do anything, but sometimes you'll need to put a few pieces together and build it yourself.  When you do you can use them just like any other command.  So as you find more techniques on here you can write and collect your own set of commands that you use for your special purposes.  Also see:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239986/how-to-execute-sh-script-in-fedora-from-any-directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle filenames with spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash
OPWD=$(pwd)
cd "$1"
for MYFILE in "$2"/*
do
    if [ -f "${MYFILE##/*/}" ]
    then
        echo "removing ${MYFILE##/*/}"
        rm "${MYFILE##/*/}"
    fi
done
cd "$OPWD"
```

Comment: Can you show how to put this in a shell script?  So it could be called as `finddel dir1 dir2`?

Comment: hence the 'quick and dirty'...

Comment: hence the 'quick and dirty' :-) changed one of the versions to handle with filenames containing spaces...

Comment: This will fail unless `$2` is an absolute path. Also, if the `cd "$1"` fails for some reason (e.g. `$1` doesn't exist) you could end up removing the wrong files.

Answer (score 4):

Another quickie, also without an explicit loop. Don't forget, you can prefix the `rm -f` with `echo` to test this out.

```
( cd dir2 && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 ) | ( cd dir1 && xargs -0 rm -f )
```

You can put this into a script, replacing `dir1` with `"$1"` and `dir2` with `"$2"`

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer...

```
#!/bin/bash
#finddel dir1 dir2

for i in $(ls $1)
    do
    [ -f $2/$i ] && echo "Deleting $2/$i" && rm -f $2/$i
done
```

Comment: And this one removes the files from dir2 instead of dir1....

Comment: Need to quote all your variables, and don't loop over `ls` output.

Answer (score -1):

Use `rsync` :

```
rsync --verbose --remove-source-files xyz/* .
pop3-2.dump
pop3-3.dump
pop3.dump
popcorn-build.log

sent 852,069,995 bytes  received 124 bytes  113,609,349.20 bytes/sec
total size is 851,861,745  speedup is 1.00
```

Comment: This will break horrendously if the files in the two directories weren't intended to be the same.

Comment: You're right @roaima... He said "same file name". I was thinking in remove files that was accidentally copied to another directory